# What are flags, discord js

Tags: discord.js

```
'id' => User {
      id: 'id',
      username: 'name',
      bot: false,
      discriminator: '5934',
      avatar: 'a35fb962a0cc48d957a07ce36ab73a9c',
      flags: [UserFlags],
      lastMessageID: null,
      lastMessageChannelID: null
```

What does flags: [UserFlags] mean ?
I removed the id and name for privacy purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserFlags) and [Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#user-object-user-flags) documentation, flags are the "badges" on your profile for things such as HypeSquad and Discord Employees.